# DNS lookup failure while configuration is okay

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, bind, dig

I have configured my DNS using [OpenPanel](http://www.openpanel.com) and it didn't report any errors. It just adds a DNS config file which is included `/etc/bind/named.conf`. When I do

```
 named-checkconf /etc/bind/named.conf
```

which finishes without reporting any errors, by the virtue of which I assume my configuration is not faulty.

However when I do `dig @localhost google.com` I get the following:

> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 49903
>
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

in the answers section. Also, using [IntoDNS](http://intodns.com) I get this:

> ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
>
> The ones that did not respond are:
>
> (My IP address)

And -- of course -- when I try to visit my website using its FQN I get a "server not found" error.

How can I dig up the root of this problem? Where should I be looking?

Comment: Check your nameserver logs for something that we can use to help you debug this. You may also want to run `dig +trace` to see what's going on with your request...

Comment: Thank you. This is now solved. I realized that the datacenter that hosted my VPS was having some network issues, and their NICs were disabled for a short time.